# How to check if word boundary has all zero using regex

Tags: regex

I am writing regex to validate contact number. I am using following regex for validation as :

```
^(?!\b(0)\1+\b)(?!(-))([+]?(\d{1,3})?[\s.-]?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$)
```

I do not want to match input like "+00 (000) 000-0000" using this regex.
The regex should not match "+00 (000) 000-0000".
I was trying to fix this by using "word boundary should not contains all zero" but not sure how to do it.

Please suggest how to fix this. Any pointer would help.

Thanks

Comment: That input looks to match as desired..? https://regex101.com/r/bBT3uF/1

Comment: Sorry , I  mean The regex should not match "+00 (000) 000-0000".

Comment: Why don't you make it simple? Remove all the non-digits part `\D`, and check if its all zero `^0+$`

Comment: You mean to use second regex to remove non digit and check for all zero ?  I am trying it using single regex and not sure how to do it

Comment: After`^` add `(?![0\s()+-]+$)`

Answer (score 0):

You have whitespaces, `(`, `)`, `+` and `-` symbols allowed beside digits. So, if you prohibit the string to contain these symbols and `0` digit only, you will achieve the effect you want.

Add the `(?![0\s()+-]+$)` negative lookahead after `^` so that it could be executed at the very start of the string.

```
^(?![0\s()+-]+$)(?!-)([+]?(\d{1,3})?[\s.-]?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WM3bL1/2).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reject the match if the phone number has all zeroes, you can enforce the presence of a non-zero number using a positive look ahead `(?=.*[1-9])`

```
^(?=.*[1-9])(?!-)([+]?(\d{1,3})?[\s.-]?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]?\d{3}[\s.-]?\d{4}$)
 ^^^^^^^^^^^ This ensures the number have at least one non-zero number
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ASAgQ0/1/)**